# how to connect asp.net core MVC project to local DB using Entity Framework Core on ubuntu desktop

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ubuntu-16.04

I'm Building an asp.net core application using Entity Framework Core on Ubuntu 16.04 desktop.
I have SQL Server installed and running.
I've run the command "-dotnet ef migrations Initial" successfully. I'm prepared to run "-dotnet ef database update" to allow EF to connect to and create the table in the database but I'm receiving this error on the terminal:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP
>   Provider, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid)

it's a local DB so I'm thinking I don't need a TCP provider, right?
how do I tell EF to connect to SQL server?

Comment: not sure if local DB is available on ubuntu

Comment: how would, then, 2 different developers working on the same asp.net core app and pushing their work to github go about developing locally since the appsettings.json would be the same for both, but the developer working on Ubuntu would have to use a different DB for testing the application.
how is this usually solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify your connection string on **appsettings.json** file

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=YOUR_SERVER_NAME;Database=DBNAME;User Id=sa;Password=PASSWORD;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  }
}
```